# How to return return boolean false if strings has empty spaces

Tags: javascript

How to check for blank space in javascript.

My code:

```js
function checkSubstring(text, part) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
    if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(part.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || part.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
      return true;
    }
    else if (text === ' ' || part === ' ') {
      return false
    }
  }
  return false
}

console.log(checkSubstring(' ', '  '));
```

I tried check if white space using indexOf(' '), check if strings === 0 but it always return true.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: `<= text.length` should be `< text.length`

Comment: Why do you have a loop? You're never using `text[i]`.

Comment: Why do you have backticks around `|| part.toUpperCase().toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase().toLowerCase()) !== -1){`? That's not valid syntax.

Comment: Why do you call both `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`?

Comment: the back tick was a mistake

Comment: Wouldn't you need both to.UpperCase().toLowerCase() to check for cas sensitive>

Comment: use `trim()`???

Answer (score 0):

Change your function as below

```
 function checkSubstring(text, part) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
        if (text.trim().length === 0 || part.trim().length === 0) {
                return false
        }
        if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(part.toLowerCase()) !== -1 || part.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).